# Laravel: Same Variable not working in different view

Tags: laravel

If i use the variable tests everything works:

My Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $row = Test::count();
    $tests = Test::latest()->paginate($row);
    return view('tests.index',compact('tests'));
}

public function show(Test $test)
{
    return view('tests.show', compact('test'));
}
```

My Index-View:

```
@foreach($tests as $test)
   <div class="event">
     <h4 class="eventtitle text-j4y-dark">{{ $test->body }}</h4>
     <a href="{{ route('tests.show', $test->id) }}">Mehr lesen »</a>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

My Show-View:

```
<h4 class="eventtitle text-j4y-dark">{{ $test->body }}</h4>
```

but if i use the variable event the index page wokrs so it shows me all of my events but if i click on one event for more details it shows me nothing and nothing works but i don't know why? its the same code only different variables ?
I don't know what to do

My Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $row = Event::count();
    $events = Event::latest()->paginate($row);
    return view('tests.index',compact('events'));
}

public function show(Event $event)
{
    return view('tests.show', compact('event'));
}
```

My Index-View:

```
@foreach ($events as $event)
  <div class="event">
    <h4 class="eventtitle text-j4y-dark">{{ $event->eventtitel }}</h4>
    <div class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>{{ date("d.m.Y", strtotime($event->datum)) }}</div>
    <p class="eventtext" id="eventtext">{{ $event->eventbeschreibung }}</p>
    <a href="{{ route('tests.show', $event->id) }}">Mehr lesen »</a>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

My Show-View:

```
<div class="event">
  <h4 class="eventtitle">{{ $event->eventtite l}}</h4>
  <div class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>{{ date("d.m.Y", strtotime($event->datum)) }}</div>
  <p class="eventtext" id="eventtext">{{ $event->eventbeschreibung }}</p>
</div>
```

if i use dd($test) it shows me this:

```
Test {#692 ▼
#fillable: array:1 [▶]
#connection: "mysql"
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:4 [▶]
#original: array:4 [▶]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#guarded: array:1 [▶]
 }
```

if i use dd($event) it shows me this:

```
Event {#660 ▼
#fillable: array:5 [▶]
+timestamps: false
#connection: null
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: false
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: []
#original: []
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#guarded: array:1 [▶]
```

}

if i use echo $event in my controller 
it shows me this: []

if i use print_r($event)

it shows me this:

```
App\Event Object ( [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => firmenname [1] => eventtitel [2] => eventbeschreibung [3] => datum [4] => anhang ) [timestamps] => [connection:protected] => [table:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [keyType:protected] => int [incrementing] => 1 [with:protected] => Array ( ) [withCount:protected] => Array ( ) [perPage:protected] => 15 [exists] => [wasRecentlyCreated] => [attributes:protected] => Array ( ) [original:protected] => Array ( ) [changes:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [dateFormat:protected] => [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) )
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i dont get a error i only get a empty page

Comment: try to return $test or dd($test) in show method?

Comment: Event {#660 ▼
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  +timestamps: false
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

Comment: and if i use the variable test (here works everything)

Test {#692 ▼
  #fillable: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:4 [▶]
  #original: array:4 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

Comment: please add all this in your question to ake it readbale toevery one and in your show method try to return $test;

Comment: i add everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are lot of issue with you code. First thing is the pagination.

```
$row = Event::count(); //This is basically counting all the events you have
$events = Event::latest()->paginate($row); // And here u telling to pageinit with all events in single page.
```

I personally do not think it is the right way. If I had to do I would do this way

```
 $events = Event::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();  //This will allthe even in single page with the latest one.
```

If you only need all the events and sorting is not required I would do like this

```
 $events = Event::all(); //This is give all the events
```

Coming back to your question.

A variable defined inside a controller method stays inside that method and the view that method is rendering. It does not pass another blade until and unless you are declaring it globally in the provider.

**For your case, i would do something like this**

*Route*

```
Route::get('events',['as'=>'events','uses'=>'ControllerName@index']);
Route::get('event/{id}',['as'=>'event.detail','uses'=>'ControllerName@show']);
```

*Controller*

```
public function index()
{
    $data['events'] = Event::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get(); 
    return view('tests.index',$data);
}

public function show($id)
{
  $data['eventDetail'] = Event::where('id',$id)->first();
  return view('tests.show',$data);
}
```

**Index view**

```
@foreach ($events as $event)
  <div class="event">
    <h4 class="eventtitle text-j4y-dark">{{ $event->eventtitel }}</h4>
   <<CODE HERE MORE CODE >>
    <a href="{{route('event.detail',['id'=>$event->id]) }}">Mehr lesen »</a>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

**Event detail view**

```
<div class="event">
  <h4 class="eventtitle">{{ $eventDetail->eventtite l}}</h4>
  <div class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>{{ date("d.m.Y", strtotime($eventDetail->datum)) }}</div>
  <p class="eventtext" id="eventtext">{{ $eventDetail->eventbeschreibung }}</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you it works :) but do you know why it works with the variable $test but not with the variable $event? so i dont know whats wrong

Comment: I am not sure, probably something to do with test function laravel has test function [ Although i m not sure about it]